# decimal value pulled from DB not displaying calculation result

Tags: php, decimal

OK in the DB i have a table with 2x columns ( DECIMAL 10,5 )
target = 113.889;
sell = 123.894;

As you can see the target value is lower than the sell value
So here is my code below

```
    if($alertr['action'] = '1') // BUY
    { 
        if($sell > $target)
        {
         echo "Target Reached";
        } 
        else 
        {
         echo "Still Going";
        }

    }
```

However it echos Still Going which is wrong as $sell is greater than $target

Comment: `$sell>$target` and `$target<$sell` are the same condition

Comment: have amended code.
Doesnt work as it says still going despite the fact $sell is greater than $target

Comment: put `var_dump($sell, $target);` above `if($sell` to see what they contain. btw, `if ($alertr['action'] = '1')` is assigning the value of `action` to `1`..

Comment: Thanks for helping me spot that .. the current sell price was in fact lower than the target , was looking at wrong table :)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my other mistake :)